# uber Auth0 unauthorized api calls

Tags: dotnet-httpclient, auth0, uber-api

im getting unauthorized error when calling https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price

I'm using Auth0 and can successfully login with scopes profile request and all_trips.

I get the id.token from the result and pass it to client header

```
_authHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = _authHeader;
```

Answer (score 2):

If using a `server_token` and not an oauth access token the header should be "Authorization: Token ". See the example in the [curl guide](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/curl#get-products-with-a-server-token).